# Child_of in Wordpress called with a variable not just returning childs

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type, custom-fields

**Situation**

I am using the Advanced Custom Fields plugin to give Custom Post Types a checkbox. If this box is checked, it should be returned by this Query. The Query works this far.

**The issue**

The pages I want it to display are all childs of a page. And this Query returns all pages with the checkbox, instead of just the childs of the current page with the checkbox.

**My code**

*top of page*

```
<?php $tid = get_the_ID(); ?>
```

*Further along the page*

```
<?php
  $i == 0;
  global $post;
  $myposts = new WP_Query(array(
     'post_type' => 'keuringen',
     'child_of' => $tid,
     'meta_query' => array(
         array(
         'key' => 'first_to_load',
         'value' => '1',
         'compare' => '=='
         )
     )
  ));
?>
```

**The question**
What can I do to make it return only the children? Or should this already return only the children and is this a bug in one of the plugins?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it's not about programming, but WordPress inner workings. Belongs on [wordpress.se].

Comment: Since I thought that there might be something wrong with my code I thought it might fit here. It's a bit of a grey area.

Comment: I see it as pure `WP_Query` issue. Did you research the topic over there?

Comment: I did and found nothing related, neither did I find anything related here. That's why I made a new question

Comment: I don't see any `child_of` as a WPQuery parameter. There is [**`post_parent`**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Post_.26_Page_Parameters), though...

Comment: **Resolved** Someone on the Wordpress Answers page explained the difference with post_parent and child_of, thanks for the help and redirecting me.

Comment: Post your solution, so this Q doesn't remain "unanswered" :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use post_parent instead of child_of in WP_Query